# How to find values that contains only 0's and any other digit for example 000000001 or 0000010001 or 010101 or 0002 or 02020 or 0090 etc.?

Tags: sql, sql-server, combinations, default-value

I want to find 'default type values' in SQL that is entered when something like an ID number of company registration number is entered. Some of the values I see is a combination of 0's and another digit from 1-9. Examples I have seen is 00000001, 0000100, 000000002, 000001111, 0000090009, etc. The values vary in length also. Is there a way to find these values without hard coding? The value should contain at least one 0 and one or more of any other digit.

Comment: Hi, what database do you use ? Oracle, MySQL or SQLServer or something else ?

Comment: By "only 0 and any other digit", do you mean "numbers only"? The answer is yes and depends on your specific RDBMS, so as the *`sql` tag* description clearly recommends, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS and its version.

Comment: I use SQLServer

Comment: Do you mean at least one 0 and one or more of just one different digit only? So that non-matches would include 00000, 01020, 11111?

Comment: @MikeBeaton yes, at least one 0 and one or more of just one different digit only

Comment: @PauliduPlooy - Maybe update the question to clarify (as you don't really explicitly say this yet, just imply it by the examples)?

Answer (score 2):

You want all strings that consist of only zero and one other digit. I.e. you want to find '0101', but not '0102'.

In order to do this, remove all zeros first. From the remaining string remove all digits equaling to its first character. This will result in an empty string or a string consisting of additional digits or characters. Only select those resulting in an empty string.

```
select *
from mytable
where replace(replace(value, '0', ''), substring(replace(value, '0', ''), 1, 1), '') = '';
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c307bbbf21ceeae619a966e995c3a567

Comment: Nice approach - though if it's an arbitrary string (may contain characters other than 0-9), you'd also need to check that the remaining first character after removing the 0's actually is a digit 1-9.

Comment: Also, for the requirements as clarified in the OP comments, I believe the OP wants at least one zero, and at least 1 of the other digit - which are two further checks (as you'd currently allow zero 0's, and zero of the other digit). But still nice approach (which can definitely be extended with the needed(?) extras checks)! :)

Comment: @MikeBeaton: Thank you. You are right, the OP may have to make little adjustments to cover all requirements.

Comment: To match the additional requirements, you can add `AND substring(replace(value, '0', ''), 1, 1) LIKE '[1-9]' AND value LIKE '%0%'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ISNUMERIC() function

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC(0000004);
```

This will return 1

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC('A');
```

This will return 0

So if you want to select all columns that are numeric only you can use this logic:

```
select *
from test
where ISNUMERIC(colA) = 1
```

[Here is a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=409e284e8e1477eb77be47685072ac0a)

Or you can use TRY_CAST() function:

```
select *
from test
where try_cast(colA as int) is not null
```

Comment: ISNUMERIC is a [terrible suggestion](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/why-doesn%e2%80%99t-isnumeric-work-correctly-sql-spackle).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

```
SELECT value
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT '1' AS num
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '3'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '4'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '5'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '6'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '7'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '8'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '9'
) n
WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(value, '0', ''), num, '') = ''
AND REPLACE(value, '0', '') <> ''
AND value LIKE '%0%'
```